# Did I just lose three fans? Or just one?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, deleted-users

Here's what I've got in the *achievements* menu:

[image]

`-10`, then `-5`, then `-30`.

Is there some kind of grouping explaining this in a detailed list or were three distinct users removed at the same time?

Note that a more compact message, with all changes grouped, is visible in my main reputation tab. I don't know how those information are to be conciliated.

*Obviously this isn't an important question, and the reputation loss doesn't matter at all, but now I'm curious...*

Comment: Let's keep extended discussions out of comments and in chat, I [created a chatroom for this discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78827/discussion-on-question-by-denys-seguret-did-i-just-lose-three-fans-or-just-one).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You didn't really "lose three fans" so much as three accounts were removed. Sock-puppet accounts. Unfortunately, these users hit a *lot* of folks - their vote percentages back to the puppet-master were only about 50-60% each, which means there were also quite a lot of votes to other users not related to that person.

In most cases, these users *also* voted for the same posts of those other users that did end up receiving their votes. Some users saw losses of much more reputation than the 45 you lost. It sucks, yes, but the votes were also fraudulent. You were receiving multiple votes on posts from *one user* who was accessing the site from multiple accounts, and the reputation changes are fair to the community in that they fix something that really shouldn't have happened.

The achievements menu still groups the net gain/loss from a user removal *by user*, which means each user will appear as a separate entry. The reputation history used to do the same thing, but was recently changed to just roll them all up into one "user was removed" event which no longer indicates how many users were actually involved, only how much reputation was lost due to that reason (although I'm not personally aware if that was an intentional change or not).

Comment: @GrantWinney: Why? The puppet-master has to try *something* to camouflage his socks... or it would come home to roost *much* faster.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I can infer from your diamond that when you say that what I see is the consequence of 3 removed accounts you're not just guessing ?

Comment: "The achievements menu still groups the net gain/loss from a user removal by user". I don't think so. Here's my achievements from last week where, through a comment exchange (since deleted), I know that Brad Larson deleted (or caused to be deleted) one user: http://i.stack.imgur.com/c2tlW.png. Those removed votes are *per post* (Answer in these cases) in my achievements.

Comment: @BillWoodger That is odd and I'd consider that a bug because a) it's not consistent with how it's always been displayed and b) it's just plain annoying if a user hits a lot of your posts. I've seen users who unknowingly receive 20+ upvotes from someone else's sock-puppet, and I'd really hope we don't dump a list of 20 "user was removed" events into their achievements menu now.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I'm the one that handled the removal of the three accounts involved here and understand the voting patterns that were present on them.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Would you like to report the bug referred to by animuson? I certainly can't see any point in seven "User was deleted" links which just take me to my profile when I click on them and can't believe it is supposed to be like that.  I suppose we're in "doesn't happen often" territory :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger No, I won't report any bug here, as I don't really see that as a real problem

Comment: @DenysSéguret Me too, then.  If there's ever a flood of duplicate questions someone may post the bug :-)